# Call PHP from virtual/custom "web server"

Tags: php, cgi, webserver, fastcgi, mod-php

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how PHP can be called from a "web server".

I've read the documentation, but it didn't help much.

As far as I can tell, there are three ways to invoke PHP:

- via command line (eg: `php -f "/path/to/script.php"`)
- via CGI(??) / via FastCGI (???)
- via a web server (eg: Apache) module

So let's start with [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface). Maybe I'm just blind, but the spec doesn't mention how on Earth the web server passes data (headers & callbacks) to the thing implementing CGI. The situation is even worse with [FastCGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI).

Next up, we have server-specific modules, which, I don't even know what to search for since all leads end up nowhere.

Comment: Have you considered reading the code? All of these things in your question are open source.

Comment: @Dan I'm *trying* to do that right now. But it's proving difficult for several reasons: **(1)** I can't find all the code **(2)** the code is in c/c++ **(3)** the code is very old and/or messy.

Comment: @Dan says who?? I could do it in Assembler or ADA if I wanted to (or FPC, which I'm planning to).

Comment: Yelling at the wind won't help you. http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-robinson-www-interface-00

Comment: Here is a CGI module written in PHP, might be easier to follow than the typical guides: http://code.google.com/p/nanoweb-instant/source/browse/work/five_tani/modules/mod_cgi.php - Don't bother with FastCGI, not worth the effort (and PHP doesn't support the simpler SCGI.)

Comment: @Dan - Seen that already, see my 3rd para.

Comment: @mario - **Thanks, excellent response, as always.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Invoking a CGI script is pretty simple. PHP has a few peculiarities, but you basically only need to setup a list of environment variables, then call the PHP-CGI binary:

```
setenv GATEWAY_INTERFACE="CGI/1.1"
setenv SCRIPT_FILENAME=/path/to/script.php
setenv QUERY_STRING="id=123&name=title&parm=333"
setenv REQUEST_METHOD="GET"
...

exec /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

Most of them are boilerplate. `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is how you pass the actual php filename to the PHP interpreter, not as exec parameter. Crucial for PHP is also the non-standard variable `REDIRECT_STATUS=200`.

For a GET request you only need the environment variables. For a POST request, you simply pipe the HTTP request body as `stdin` to the executed php-cgi binary. The returned `stdout` is the CGI response consisting of an incomplete HTTP header, \r\n\r\n, and the page body.

(Just from memory. There maybe a few more gotchas.)

Comment: I faced the issue then you need to populate `PATH_INFO` and `SCRIPT_PATH` variables explicitly. Please check [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962960) for details

Answer (score 1):

FastCGI is probably the best option since it's so wisely used, it would give you language independence (you could drop in Ruby later, for example) and it's [well documented](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/fcgi-spec.html) with [lots](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/mod_fcgid/trunk/modules/fcgid/) [of](http://lxr.evanmiller.org/http/source/http/modules/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.c) [examples](http://svn.cherokee-project.com/filedetails.php?repname=Cherokee&path=%2Fcherokee%2Ftrunk%2Fcherokee%2Fhandler_fcgi.c).

You could write your own [Server API](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/sapi/) if you really want, but it's trickier than implementing FastCGI and has several disadvantages.

I wouldn't bother at all with straight CGI, FastCGI exists for a reason.

Comment: OK, how does the web server do IPC with the PHP executable? local(loopback) connection?

Comment: @Christian it could be on a different host (an arbitrary TCP/IP connection) or at the other end of a unix pipe. Do read the spec I linked to, it's quite plainly written.

Comment: I'll give it a good look after a few hours' sleep. It's 2:30am already :/