# How do web servers fill $_POST & $_GET?

Tags: java, php, post, get

I am writing a Java web server and right now I am able to service .HTML files fine, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to handle .PHP files which require $_POST and $_GET.

How do web servers usually fill these arrays? There is no way to fill them using the command-line from what I can tell since I was originally thinking to pipe the stdout of an exec("php whatever.php some $_get args), but that's not possible without physically changing the php code to exploding the args and filling them into $_GET which I don't want to do -- I want to do it the way web servers do it.

Does anyone have suggestions of how web servers do things like this?

Comment: This might help: http://www.php.net/manual/en/java.servlet.php

Comment: Also you cannot use the normal `php` interpreter. You need the **`php-cgi`** variant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047426/call-php-from-virtual-custom-web-server/7047581#7047581

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use interface with PHP via [Common Gateway Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) (CGI), which boils down to setting up a bunch of environment variables and then invoking PHP.

```
REQUEST_METHOD="GET"
QUERY_STRING="param1=value1&param2=value2"
```

The CGI protocol is defined in [RFC 3875](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875).