# How I create a web server that can interact with mobile applications?

Tags: php, mobile, webserver

Ok first of all I want to create a web server that can interact with php, Mysql or mango db and mobile applications. 
What do you think is better to use Java or Python? 
I would like some good articles about web servers and how to interact with php ... For example I managed to create an simple web server but I don't know how to run php on it , and how can I make a mobile app to connect on it...
I would really appreciate some tips about these sort of things and some good tutorials ...

Comment: This question probably belongs to Programmers, I've mistakingly marked it as not constructive. Try to move it there please, thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to write your own web server? Can't you use apache or lighttpd or some other Web server that already exists?

Comment: well it's mostly for learning purposes ... thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Server as webserver base. Executing PHP within that is as simple as running a CGI interpreter. You need the `php-cgi` binary and pass some [environment variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) and possibly the POST body. It's just important to [invoke the php-cgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047426/call-php-from-virtual-custom-web-server/7047581#7047581) binary with the right environment parameters.

Also have a look at [Nanoweb](http://nanoweb.si.kz/), an existing webserver in PHP. It comes with a [`mod_cgi`](http://nanoweb.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.2.9/mod__cgi_8php-source.html) implementation.